# Evaluating stability of a period-2 orbit with one imaginary roots and one real roots

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

Consider a map:

$g\left ( x \right )=x+\lambda x\left ( 2x-1 \right )\left ( x-1 \right ) $for $[0,1)$ and $\lambda \in (0,8]$.

**It is given that $x_{-}$ and  $x_{+}
$ forms a period -2 orbit.**

It is also given that $ g'\left ( x_{-} \right )g'\left ( x_{-} \right )=\left ( \lambda-5 \right )^{2}$.

Observe that $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} g^{2}\left ( x \right )=\frac{d}{dt}\left ( g\left ( g\left ( x \right ) \right ) \right )
=g'\left (g\left ( x_{+} \right )  \right ) g'\left ( x_{+} \right )=g'\left ( x_{-} \right )g'\left ( x_{+} \right )=
\left ( \lambda -5 \right )^{2}$

Let $\bar{\lambda}$ denote the eigenvalue $g'\left (g\left ( x_{+} \right )  \right ) g'\left ( x_{+} \right )=g'\left ( x_{-} \right )g'\left ( x_{+} \right )
\left ( \lambda -5 \right )^{2}$

The stability of a period-2 orbit can be evaluated by taking the absolute value of the time derivative of the eigenvalue.

Hence, $\left | \bar{\lambda} \right |=\left | \left ( \lambda-5 \right )^{2} \right |< or >1 $

To check for stable period 2 orbit: $\left | \left ( \lambda-5 \right )^{2} \right |<1$

This is

$\left ( \lambda-5 \right )^{2} <1$ which gives root values of 6 and 4  (which should be picked?)

We should also check for $\left ( \lambda-5 \right )^{2}>-1$

But the roots are imaginary; in particular, they are $10\pm i$ (again, which should be picked?)

I would like to know how I can reconcile the two real root values of which one must be picked and the imaginary roots so that I can determined the stability of the period-2 orbit and sketch a bifurcation diagram.

Edit:

$x_{\pm }=\frac{1}{2}\left ( 1\pm \sqrt{1-\frac{4}{\lambda}} \right )$

Comment: What do you mean by "$g'(x_-)g'(x_+)$ forms a period-$2$ orbit"? Are you trying to specify that a period-$2$ orbit passes through some point? And you haven't specified what $x_-$ or $x_+$ is.

Comment: @MichaelLee I have provided the information you required. Although, I do not see how it is related to the question.

Comment: You haven't answered the more important question. What does "$g'(x_-)g'(x_+)$ forms a period-$2$ orbit" mean? Your notation is rather unclear. Typically, we might specify an orbit of a discrete dynamical system $g : X\to X$ as something like $$\gamma(x_0) = \{g^n(x_0) : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Comment: Using this notation, do you mean that $\lvert \gamma(g'(x_-)g'(x_+))\rvert = 2$?

Comment: @MichaelLee That was a serious typo. The corrected statement has been highlighted in bold.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the correction.